# Elastic Search Api issue while adding multiple fields to a tag

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I am following the document

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html for adding a document and updating it.

The request for add is

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
    "counter" : 1,
    "tags" : ["red"]
}
```

and the one for adding a new value to the tags list is like

```
POST test/_update/1
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.tags.add(params.tag)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

which is working fine. now my issue is adding a list of values to the tag field , if I pass it like

```
"tag" : ["green","yellow"]
```

the entire list is getting added as a field. How can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to adapt the script in order to handle both cases.

One way would be to use another parameter (e.g. `tags`) to add a list of values and keep `tag` for single values:

```
POST test/_update/1
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "def set = new HashSet(ctx._source.tags); if (params.tags != null) { set.addAll(params.tags) } else if (params.tag != null) { set.add(params.tag)} ctx._source.tags = new ArrayList(set);",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tags" : ["green", "yellow"]
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add a new parameter, you can do it like this and test the nature of the `tag` value in order to run the correct operation:

```
POST test/_update/1
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "def set = new HashSet(ctx._source.tags); if (params.tag instanceof List) { set.addAll(params.tag) } else { set.add(params.tag) } ctx._source.tags = new ArrayList(set);",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : ["green", "yellow"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is adding duplicate values again and again, is there a way to avoid it ?

Comment: Yes, by using a Set instead of a List. I've modified my answer to show you how to do it